# Title for updated favorited question unreadable

Tags: bug, design, meta

On the Favorites tab of the User Profile screen, the title of an updated question becomes unreadable as it blends in with the background.

[image: Unread Updated Favorite Question]

Once clicked through, the Title and background colors change such as to become readable.

[image: Read Updated Favorite Question]